# SikuliX IDE to fill more than one input field

Tags: sikuli, sikuli-ide

I try to use `SikuliX IDE` to fill more than one input fields on the same screen. All the fields look like the same. I captured input field, `click` on it and use `type` to set value, but text is not present after that process.

Answer (score 0):

Try wait() function between your actions, sometimes you need to wait the gui to get ready for your next action. The default time gap between actions may too tight.